# Google App Engine | domain name mapping | Go Daddy domain name

Tags: domain, godaddy, mapping, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Right now I have no ahost records set in Godaddy. I read something
that said I should set it to 64.202.189.170, but I think that's for the
case of domain name forwarding, NOT mapping, and that's not what I
want.
I already added my domain name to [GAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) and confirmed my ownership of
the domain name.
I also already added www to GAE and added a cname record of www
pointing to ghs.google.com.

Then I tried access www.mydomain.com but it keeps forwarding to
myappname.appspot.com.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what to do other than wait 48
hours? Should I have an ahost record set? If so what should I set it
to?

PS: I read over this Q&A, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain.

Comment: this article http://sam.curren.ws/index.cfm/2008/4/17/Google-AppEngine-Using-your-own-domain says that i SHOULD have an a host record that points to google's ip address, and that mydomainname.com should be set to forward to www.mydomainname.com  but if i set my a host record to point to googles ip address www.mydomainname.com shows google's main search page. again not what i want

Comment: okay so i tried a different subdomain other than www. i tried calendar.myappname.com . that works. www.myappname.com still doesn't work. makes me wonder if this is a built in restriction or something. ive read in so many different places that this works. even the google docs hint that www works.

Answer (score 4):

You should not set A records to static IPs for App Engine. Set a CNAME for the 'www' subdomain to ghs.google.com, as you say you have, ensure everything is configured correctly in Google Apps, and give it 24 hours or so to make sure everything's propagated. If you want the 'naked' domain to redirect to the www domain, use Godaddy's redirection features to achieve this.

Comment: waiting 24 hours did the trick. it works now. thanks!